# Where do I find the list of patents and designs for a given company?

Tags: design-patent, patent-services

Is there a way to look up patents and designs in the UK and USA for a given company?

Comment: Did you try searching Google (patents) by the name?

Comment: @RonJ. "name", what do you mean?

Comment: @RonJ. Lets say I want to search all patents by stack exchange inc, what would I put in the search box in http://www.google.com/patents ?

Comment: You can use google patents *advanced* and put the company name in the field "original assignee". It is imperfect for many reasons. Company names change, they have subsidiaries with similar but different names and also patents are bought and sold. The original assignee may not be the current owner.

Answer (score 1):

USPTO and FreePatentsOnline both allow the "an/" specifier for assignee, so you can search for "an/google" or "an/microsoft" for the most part. (Per George White's comment, it doesn't help follow business transactions e.g. subsidiaries and sales.)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to look up patents and designs in the UK and USA for a given company?

For USPTO patents: https://idiyas.com

E.g., for IBM: https://idiyas.com/company/62ffa188e837f6b92cdcaec5

[image]